Duplicate class found Error in Android studio.(androidx.core:core:x.x.x)
My App was working okay, but I tried to rebuild my app but I keep getting these Errors
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules core-1.13.0.aar -> core-1.13.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.13.0) and support-compat-28.0.0.aar -> support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules core-1.13.0.aar -> core-1.13.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.13.0) and support-compat-28.0.0.aar -> support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.13.0.aar -> core-1.13.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.13.0) and support-compat-28.0.0.aar -> support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.IconCompatParcelizer found in modules core-1.13.0.aar -> core-1.13.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.13.0) and support-compat-28.0.0.aar -> support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules core-1.13.0.aar -> core-1.13.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.13.0) and support-compat-28.0.0.aar -> support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in modules core-1.13.0.aar -> core-1.13.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.13.0) and support-compat-28.0.0.aar -> support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.13.0.aar -> core-1.13.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.13.0) and support-compat-28.0.0.aar -> support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules core-1.13.0.aar -> core-1.13.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.13.0) and support-compat-28.0.0.aar -> support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules core-1.13.0.aar -> core-1.13.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.13.0) and support-compat-28.0.0.aar -> support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules core-1.13.0.aar -> core-1.13.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.13.0) and support-compat-28.0.0.aar -> support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules core-1.13.0.aar -> core-1.13.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.13.0) and support-compat-28.0.0.aar -> support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.core.graphics.drawable.IconCompatParcelizer found in modules core-1.13.0.aar -> core-1.13.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.13.0) and support-compat-28.0.0.aar -> support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.core.internal.package-info found in modules core-1.13.0.aar -> core-1.13.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.13.0) and support-compat-28.0.0.aar -> support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.CustomVersionedParcelable found in modules versionedparcelable-1.1.1.aar -> versionedparcelable-1.1.1-runtime (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1) and versionedparcelable-28.0.0.aar -> versionedparcelable-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.NonParcelField found in modules versionedparcelable-1.1.1.aar -> versionedparcelable-1.1.1-runtime (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1) and versionedparcelable-28.0.0.aar -> versionedparcelable-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.ParcelField found in modules versionedparcelable-1.1.1.aar -> versionedparcelable-1.1.1-runtime (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1) and versionedparcelable-28.0.0.aar -> versionedparcelable-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.ParcelImpl found in modules versionedparcelable-1.1.1.aar -> versionedparcelable-1.1.1-runtime (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1) and versionedparcelable-28.0.0.aar -> versionedparcelable-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.ParcelImpl$1 found in modules versionedparcelable-1.1.1.aar -> versionedparcelable-1.1.1-runtime (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1) and versionedparcelable-28.0.0.aar -> versionedparcelable-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.ParcelUtils found in modules versionedparcelable-1.1.1.aar -> versionedparcelable-1.1.1-runtime (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1) and versionedparcelable-28.0.0.aar -> versionedparcelable-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcel found in modules versionedparcelable-1.1.1.aar -> versionedparcelable-1.1.1-runtime (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1) and versionedparcelable-28.0.0.aar -> versionedparcelable-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcel$1 found in modules versionedparcelable-1.1.1.aar -> versionedparcelable-1.1.1-runtime (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1) and versionedparcelable-28.0.0.aar -> versionedparcelable-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcel$ParcelException found in modules versionedparcelable-1.1.1.aar -> versionedparcelable-1.1.1-runtime (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1) and versionedparcelable-28.0.0.aar -> versionedparcelable-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelParcel found in modules versionedparcelable-1.1.1.aar -> versionedparcelable-1.1.1-runtime (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1) and versionedparcelable-28.0.0.aar -> versionedparcelable-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelStream found in modules versionedparcelable-1.1.1.aar -> versionedparcelable-1.1.1-runtime (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1) and versionedparcelable-28.0.0.aar -> versionedparcelable-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelStream$FieldBuffer found in modules versionedparcelable-1.1.1.aar -> versionedparcelable-1.1.1-runtime (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1) and versionedparcelable-28.0.0.aar -> versionedparcelable-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelable found in modules versionedparcelable-1.1.1.aar -> versionedparcelable-1.1.1-runtime (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1) and versionedparcelable-28.0.0.aar -> versionedparcelable-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelize found in modules versionedparcelable-1.1.1.aar -> versionedparcelable-1.1.1-runtime (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1) and versionedparcelable-28.0.0.aar -> versionedparcelable-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.


I did see some "solutions" which said to add android.enablejetifier=true which somehow adds much more errors to my code especially my MainActivity.kt basically making the whole code unusable.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can try cleaning the build, and then rebuild the project again. It worked for me.

I tried it before but It didn't work for me sadly.

Did you try invalidating the cache and restarting the IDE?

Ofcourse I did.

You can try figuring out duplicate dependencies and then manually remove them. You can take reference from here:
https://developer.android.com/build/dependency-resolution-errors#duplicate_classes
